# The TLS connection was non-properly terminated

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am using BitBucket. I have a repository installed on my server with

```
git clone https://******@bitbucket.org/******/myproject.git
```

I was able to pull and push from my server to the bitbucket.org repository.

Now in the past days there was a warning when I pulled, that the IP of bitbucket will change on 01.08.2018.

Today I tried to push to the bitbucket repository and got the following error message:

```
git pull origin master
```

> fatal: unable to access
>   'https://******@bitbucket.org/******/myproject.git/':
>   gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly
>   terminated.

Is there an easy way hot wo fix it? Or do I have to clone the repository again to a new folder and delete the old version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're connecting over IPv6, there was an incident just a little while ago: https://status.bitbucket.org/incidents/vhwmrlvp1nh5

Answer (score 14):

For anyone facing this issue after 2020, Use ipv4 by using "--ipv4" or "-4" flag in your git command.

ex: `git clone <git url> -4`

I am not sure why this happens but sometimes IPV6 connections are not able to establish a TLS connection but IPV4 connections have no issues.

Answer (score 5):

I tried

```
git config --global  --unset http.https://github.com.proxy
git config --global  --unset https.https://github.com.proxy
```

, but the problem still exists. The solution

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

from [this blog](https://www.cnblogs.com/schips/p/connect_https_server_but_failed_with_gnutls_handshake.html) solved my problem in the end.

Comment: This solution fixed my problem. Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
git config --global  --unset http.https://github.com.proxy
git config --global  --unset https.https://github.com.proxy
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your answer and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

You need to update origin for your repository. They changed the URL.

Comment: No, the URL hasn't changed. Where are you getting that?